# (How) can I use my Mozilla dictionaries in my texteditor?

Tags: firefox, thunderbird, text-editors, spell-check, dictionary

A large majority of the stuff I write is written online via Firefox or in emails via Thunderbird.

I use the English and German spell-checking feature a lot and I find the spell-checking works to my satisfaction.

I also write text using various flavors of text editors on windows. It would be great to use the same dictionary in my local editor as I use with my Mozilla apps, as that would reduce a lot of duplicated dictionary maintenance (adding the same word 3 times over) and I also found the Mozilla dictionary to work slightly better than then one in my texteditor. (I use PSPad atm. for simple text files / TeXnicCenter for LaTeX editing.)

**So, is it possible to use my Mozilla dictionaries in my text editor** (feel free to propose one that supports that)**?**

Comment: I do not think that this is possible. I suggest you to use openoffice or something like that with its own spellcheck/dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow this guide to integrate openoffice and thunderbird dictionaries: http://hektor.umcs.lublin.pl/~mikosmul/computing/tips/mozilla-thunderbird.html

I don't know your text editor, but if it supports myspell dictionaries the procedure is very similar.

Comment: Very nice tip, thanks. The symlink idea seems nice. I'll need to see weather that works in practice. (Concurrent access of the dictionary files by multiple apps ...)

Comment: Ok, please let me know if you can use the spellcheck dictionary under concurrency condition.

Answer (score 2):

The spell checking in PSPad sucks for German as it is case-insensitive. I recommend using the free [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org). It comes with a plugin called DSpellCheck that supports Hunspell. With the symlink method mentioned before, you should be able to use one set of dictionary files for pretty much every writing task.

Comment: thanks. Except that NP++ sucks even worse that PSPad (wrt. everything else) -- 'course it's a get-used-to thing, but I don't like NP++ too much ;-)